# Test Users unable to view product catalogue linked to App on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-nodejs-business-sdk

I am trying to have my test users access my product catalogue that is linked to my app I have set up on facebook. I have added another account to with the tester role in the app (since facebook has removed the feature to create test users).

I know this must have something to do with permissions but Im cant put my finger on it. When I try accessing the catalogue using the owned_product_catalogues tag with my main account, it works perfectly. When I try to do the same using the tester account, I get no data pulled. I dont get any error on the graph API just an empty array.

I want the app to be able to access the product_catalogue since I have provided all the correct permissions for it according to my requirements. The permissions are also active and not under review in the app.

Willing to provide more information and answer questions, I understand this issue is probably very specific.